# grails jasypt-encryption: cannot resolve import GormEncryptedStringType

Tags: grails, jasypt

I have installed jasypt-encryption, as i believe correctly:

in my BuildConfig.groovy plugins closure:

```
compile ":jasypt-encryption:1.3.1"
runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.5"
```

So i have the correct jasypt version for the corresponding hibernate version.

in my Config.groovy:

```
jasypt {
algorithm = "PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC"
providerName = "BC"
password = "test"
keyObtentionIterations = 1000
}
```

And in one of my domain classes that i need the encryption for, there is an `Groovy:unable to resolve class com.bloomhealthco.jasypt.GormEncryptedStringType` error:

```
import com.bloomhealthco.jasypt.*                       //ok
import com.bloomhealthco.jasypt.GormEncryptedStringType //error
```

So, the jasypt is imported ok, because the first import line works ok, but appears that where grails is importing from, **there is no such class as GormEncryptedStringType.** Is that so?

I am totally lost, i asked for help at grails irc channel, also i contacted the person to whom the official wiki pointed - dtanner.

Following his advice i downloaded the source from github and ran `grails test-app` in the test-jasypt folder, and all the tests passed, so, as he says, the problem should be in my project. Also in that test project the GormEncryptedStringType import works okay. Both projects are on grails 2.4.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple more ideas:
1. do a `grails clean-all` on your project and then try compiling/running again.  This will clean out more resources than just a `clean` does, and re-fetch the dependencies.  If this works, then there were some stale classes in your target directory.
2. I created a sample project that references the jasypt-encryption plugin like a normal project would (it's not a relative path like the test project in the plugin source is).  The project is located here:   https://github.com/dtanner/sample-jasypt-1-3-1-project
The changes I made to the project are:
- added the plugin reference in BuildConfig.groovy
- added the encryption configuration in Config.groovy
- added the com.foo.Bar class
- added the com.foo.BarTests integration test

If the BarTest works ok for this project, then compare this with the code that's not working and see if you can spot the difference.

Comment: The strangest thing happened - i imported your project and as the import finished also the error stopped showing. Anyway, huge thanks for your help!